# Want to script all objects which depend on a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, ssms

The 'View Dependecies' shows all the objects which depend on a table in SQL Server. Now how do I use SSMS to script all these objects in one command? Is there a free tool that does this?

Answer (score 7):

First you can try this link  [Understanding SQL Dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345449.aspx)

Second, you have multiple options to check the Dependencies

using [***sql_expression_dependencies***](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315.aspx) table, to see the dependency of X on Y, run the following query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies 
WHERE referencing_id = OBJECT_ID('X')
    AND referenced_id = OBJECT_ID('Y')
    AND referenced_schema_name = 'dbo'
    AND referenced_entity_name = 'Y'
    AND referenced_database_name IS NULL
    AND referenced_server_name IS NULL;
```

using the [**syscomments**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186293.aspx) table, SQL Server's syscomments table stores the original SQL definition statement for every view, rule, default, trigger, CHECK and DEFAULT constraint, and stored procedure in your database. That's a lot of information! You can query this table to list dependent objects using a SQL statement in the following form

```
SELECT *
FROM syscomments 
INNER JOIN sysobjects sysobj ON syscomments.id = sysobj.id
WHERE charindex('your object to check', text) > 0
```

using the [**sp_depends**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189487%28SQL.90%29.aspx) stored procedure, wich  displays information about database object dependencies, such as: the views and procedures that depend on a table or view, and the tables and views that are depended on by the view or procedure

```
EXEC sp_depends @objname = N'your object to check'
```

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks.  Helpful several years later.

Answer (score 1):

SSMS relyies on SMO to extract the dependencies. The [DependencyWalker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.dependencywalker(SQL.105).aspx) class, namely. You can wrap this in your code, and the SMO also has the posibility to script out object definitions using the [Scripter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter(SQL.105).aspx) class (which again is what SSMS uses to script object definitions too).