# Export Sitebuilder SQL Server database to Excel | CSV | MySQL

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql, sql-server, plesk

I need to migrate a customer's site which happens to be hosted in a remote Win32 environment with Sitebuilder, Plesk, SQL Server and ASP or ASP.Net, I'm not sure.

I'm used to LAMP environments, so I don't know what to do with all the files in this server. Sitebuilder and SQL Server are also new to me.

I only have access to the FTP files and to the Plesk panel control, but it doesn't even acknowledge the existence of any SQL Server database (as it usually does with MySQL databases).

So far I've only been able to think of these two options:

- Code an ASP script that writes down the database content into CSV files (wouldn't know where to start).
- Code a script that retrieves the data directly from the HTML pages (long, painful, error prone and not useful to access data available only to logged in users).

So my question is: from your experience, knowledge of this platform, and point of view, which would be my best option?

Thank you very much in advance in my first question here. Regards,

**UPDATE:** I've managed to access the server (Windows 2008 server + SQL server 2008) using remote desktop. I guess I should be able to export the database now. I'll check Management Studio to see if it can help in the process.

Comment: Can't you connect to the SQL Server through the Management Studio or Visual Studio?

Comment: Are those tools capable of connecting remotely? I have Visual Studio, but I'm not sure if it can connect with the remote server this way. Could you tell me how to do it to give it a try? TIA.

Comment: You can probably use the Server Explorer within Visual Studio.

In the Server Explorer, you right click `Data Connections`, select `Add Connection` and enter the name of the server in the window that comes up. When you have selected the name, you should also be able to connect to a specific database - and you should then select the relevant database you want to work with.

Comment: I've tried that and failed. Apparently the server is not configured to accept remote connections. So I guess I'm stuck with the other (painful) options :) :( Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds odd that it doesn't support remote connections, but if you want to do it from within your asp-pages, the following links might be good starting points:

[Want to script all objects which depend on a SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750519/want-to-script-all-objects-which-depend-on-a-sql-server-table)

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/code32-how-to-generate-create-table-script-for-all-tables-in-sql-server-database.aspx

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20355/generate-create-script-for-all-indexes

Comment: I've managed to access the server (Windows 2008 server + SQL server 2008) using remote desktop. I guess I should be able to export the database now. I'll check Management Studio to see if it can help in the process.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to both export the database itself as well as scripting all the objects from Mgmt. Studio. (Do note, however, that there are two scripting options. One will only script the database object - ie. the files, etc., but no tables. The other will provide you with the option to select which objects you want to script.)